# Mac Chess app crashes each time i open it

Tags: high-sierra, crash, macos

Some days ago I played a few Chess games on the built-in chess app. But now each time i open up chess it does these steps:

1. It makes the mouse a spinning color wheel
2. The app crashes
3. It says that 'Chess quit unexpectedly'

What can i do to fix this?

Comment: Can you post logs and software version?

Comment: My version of mac is 10.13.5 and what do you mean with logs?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is a wonderful issue to follow the two articles Apple publishes on isolating issues *(not that it's wonderful to crash, but this is a very small contained issue that should be easy to isolate and then fix)*:

- https://support.apple.com/en-us/HT203161 - Isolating issues in Mac OS X

That sets the table for you to dive into software isolation (which this is clearly the first thing to try)

- https://support.apple.com/en-us/HT201516 - Mac OS X: How to troubleshoot a software issue

In your case, making a new user account, verifying if the crash is system wide or just your account is the next step I’d take. Once that’s done, you can think about updates / verifying a backup, etc...

Comment: I don’t think the first link is correct

Comment: Yes indeed @IronCraftMan Thanks so much for pointing that out. I've added the title since the one link may be archived and that will help further fixed if these links rot in the future.

Comment: If i create a new user, Chess works fine

Comment: @VictorFink Excellent triage. So - you can move your preferences and files to the new account and delete the one with the bad settings or you can start undoing and clearing settings on the old account in hopes you learn which setting is corrupt. Which is easier for you?

Comment: At least i want to keep my account, but which settings do you mean?

Answer (score 1):

Your App Setting seems to be corrupted.

to solve the problem proceed as follow:

1. Create a new Mac User
2. Log in with that user in order to initialize it
3. Log in again into your user
4. Copy the content of this Folder:
   ‎⁨      **Macintosh HD⁩ ▸ ⁨Benutzer⁩ ▸ [New User] ▸ ⁨Library⁩ ▸ ⁨Containers⁩ ▸ ⁨com.apple.Chess⁩**
   into your Folder:
   **Macintosh HD⁩ ▸ ⁨Benutzer⁩ ▸ [Your User] ▸ ⁨Library⁩ ▸ ⁨Containers⁩ ▸ ⁨com.apple.Chess⁩**

To make hiden folders visible, just hit following keys:
**CMD + Shift + DOT**

Comment: Surely just deleting the Container in the original user account should suffice?